# Thunderbird Data reinstallation

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup, thunderbird

I have Back up of Emails in Thunderbird in OLD PC.New Laptop Purchased.
How to take backup in New Laptop -Thunderbird and what precautions to be taken

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking.  Do you want to use your old profile (emails, settings, add-ons) with the new installation?

Comment: Just place the contents of the old user profile within the new user profile

Answer (score 0):

All the personal information in a Thunderbird is contained in a [profile folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder),
(depending on your OS the url might slightly change).

I'd suggest you create a new profile in your new installation(then close thunderbird);

afterwards you go in the new-installation profile folder and change whatever has been just generated with what is inside your old-installation profile folder;

when you restart Thunderbird you should see your old profile on your new computer.

I've done it recently and it worked like a charm
(but always backup your old precious profile folder).

Answer (score 0):

1. On the new installation create a profile (say "skip/OK" to everything) and exit Thunderbird, then [locate your profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Windows_Vista.2C_7.2C_8.1_and_10) --usually: `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\`
2. On the Thunderbird/profiles directory, make a copy of the profile directory from the old installation.
3. Launch the Thunderbird profile manager: `Thunderbird -profilemanager` and [create a new profile pointing to the new folder](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder_-_Thunderbird#Use_the_Profile_Manager_to_move_your_profile) you just created in step 2
4. Done